# Checking out Lucene from their SVN

Tags: svn, lucene

I am trying to checkout lucene from their svn.
I have installed the Subeclipse plugin for eclipse, however, I am facing issues connecting to the svn repo.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: URL 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk%20lucene_trunk' non-existent in revision 1333463
```

Can you please help me solve it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene

Comment: Thanks. Will now have to move the packages. :)